# Highcharts, turn click point into link

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am working with Highcharts (https://www.highcharts.com/) to build a clickable map as it was the only option suiting what I needed. The map I am using is found on this codepen (https://codepen.io/mushigh/pen/xxRmpWy) . I have only one problem I can not possibly make it able to turn this markers as links

[Image of keypoints in the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXlO4.png)

I changed these paramerters a little bit so they would return a link but nothing worked.

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function () {
    return this.point.id + (
      this.point.lat ?
        '<br>Lat: ' + this.point.lat + ' Lon: ' + this.point.lon : ''
    );
  }
},

plotOptions: {
  series: {
    marker: {
      fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
      lineWidth: 2,
      lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
//'<button onclick="href=\'www.facebook.com\'">Kliko</button>'

    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the point's click event to achieve that. Add the following code to the series:

```
cursor: 'pointer',
  point: {
    events: {
      click() {
        let point = this;
        location.href = `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/${point.name}`
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6bh34w5k/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.mappoint.point.events.click

Comment: I tried so hard to fix it and I just got stuck , thank you so much!!